# Disabling API Explorer in App Engine

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Are there other ways to disable access on API Explorer in App Engine, aside from having OAuth restriction?

Sample scenario:
Users who succeeded the verification process with OAuth are now eligible to use the API Explorer, although, this is not what the client wants his access of API Explorer to be, but rather disable the whole API Explorer in his App Engine entirely.

Is this something you can confirm or verify?

Thanks!

Comment: The "API Explorer" is used for many APIs. Please clarify what use-case you're referring to for "use the API Explorer". Do you mean calling the App Engine API in the API Explorer to manage this client's project? Do you mean using the API Explorer to call a Cloud Endpoints API created by this client deployed to App Engine? Or something else?

Comment: Hi John, I'm currently clarifying what specific APIs that the client is referring to. Additionally, API Explorer seems to authorize any gmail account (which the client doesn't want). Is this something you can provide a workaround or fix (restrict other gmail accounts/protect his explorer API).

Comment: Hi John, sorry it took so long to provide you the information on this. Kindly check the client's use-case below:

Comment: Basically, by accessing https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://<app_name_deployed_in_AppEngine>/_ah/api any user can view the API definition of the client and run the functionality of each Cloud Endpoints API of the customer's project by easily running authentication with an email account and OAuth. We're currently running some tests on our end as well and will provide more details if we found something. This is quite troublesome indeed, any insights regarding this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it looks like you are referring to a feature of Google Cloud Endpoints Frameworks v1. I don't think a solution exists for that version to disable the APIs Explorer. However, this issue shouldn't occur when using Cloud Endpoints Frameworks v2. Because of that and since v1 is deprecated now, it sounds like your client should look into upgrading (see [java migration instructions](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating) or [python migration instructions](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/migrating)).

Comment: Hi John, thanks for looking into this, appreciate the help.